# asm error compiling huffyuv with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly

I'm trying to compile [huffyuv](http://neuron2.net/www.math.berkeley.edu/benrg/huffyuv.html) with Visual Studio 2010. I get error message A2070 when assembling an asm file. I pasted the (some of) the relevant code below:

```
YUV_SHIFT   MACRO   mmb,mma,uyvy    ; clobbers mm4,5

; mma:mmb = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP (VYUYVYUY...) - backwards from mem order
;   we want mmb = EDGFIHKJ (prev pixel of same channel)

    movq    mm4,mmb
    punpcklbw   mmb,mma     ; mm4:mmb = AIBJCKDLEMFNGOHP
    punpckhbw   mm4,mma
    movq    mm5,mmb
    punpcklbw   mmb,mm4     ; mm5:mmb = AEIMBFJNCGKODHLP
    punpckhbw   mm5,mm4
    movq    mm4,mmb
    punpcklbw   mmb,mm5     ; mm4:mmb = ACEGIKMOBDFHJLNP
    punpckhbw   mm4,mm5
    psllq   mmb,8+8*&uyvy       ; mm4:mmb = EGIKMO__DFHJLNP_
    psllq   mm4,16-8*&uyvy
    punpckhbw   mmb,mm4     ; mmb = EDGFIHKJ (for YUY2; different for UYVY)

    ENDM

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

MEDIAN_PREDICT_PROC MACRO   procname,uyvy

    PUBLIC  C _&procname

;void __cdecl mmx_MedianPredict(
;   [esp+ 4] unsigned char* src,
;   [esp+ 8] unsigned char* dst,
;   [esp+12] unsigned char* src_end,
;   [esp+16] int stride);

_&procname  PROC

    push    ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    push    edi
    push    esi
    push    ebx

    ; do the first row
    mov esi,[ebp+4+4]
    mov edi,[ebp+8+4]
    mov ebx,[ebp+16+4]
    lea ecx,[ebx+esi+8]
    neg ebx

    pxor    mm2,mm2
    movq    mm3,[esi]   ; for use in next loop

loop0:
    movq    mm0,[esi]
    YUV_SHIFT   mm2,mm0,uyvy
    add esi,8
    movq    mm1,mm0
    psubb   mm1,mm2
    movq    [edi],mm1
    movq    mm2,mm0
    add edi,8
    cmp esi,ecx
    jb  loop0

    mov ecx,[ebp+8+4]   ; recopy first group of four, just for consistency with other compression methods
    movd    [ecx],mm3

    ; do the remaining rows
    mov ecx,[ebp+12+4]
    ; mm2,3 are already initialized from previous loop

    align   32

    ; pixel arrangement:
    ;    mm3 mm1
    ;    mm2 mm0

loop1:
    ; mm2,3 <- appropriate left and above-left pixels
    movq    mm0,[esi]
    movq    mm1,[esi+ebx]

    YUV_SHIFT   mm2,mm0,uyvy    ; note: clobbers mm4,5
    add esi,8
    YUV_SHIFT   mm3,mm1,uyvy

    ; mm4 <- median of mm1,mm2,(mm1+mm2-mm3)

    movq    mm4,mm2     ; (mm2,mm4) <- (min(mm1,mm2),max(mm1,mm2))
    movq    mm5,mm2     ; mm5 <- mm1+mm2-mm3
    psubusb mm4,mm1
    paddb   mm5,mm1
    psubb   mm2,mm4
    psubb   mm5,mm3
    paddb   mm4,mm1

    psubusb mm2,mm5     ; mm2 = max(mm2,mm5)
    paddb   mm2,mm5

    movq    mm5,mm4     ; mm4 = min(mm2,mm4)
    psubusb mm5,mm2
    psubb   mm4,mm5     ; now mm4 = median

    ; write out the result and loop
    movq    mm2,mm0
    movq    mm3,mm1
    psubb   mm0,mm4
    movq    [edi],mm0
    cmp esi,ecx
    lea edi,[edi+8]
    jb  loop1

    emms
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    pop edi
    pop ebp
    retn

_&procname  ENDP

    ENDM

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

MEDIAN_PREDICT_PROC mmx_MedianPredictYUY2,0 ; I get the error on this line
MEDIAN_PREDICT_PROC mmx_MedianPredictUYVY,1 ; and this as well
```

These are the first errors I get (I get more of the same kind later, but if I know how to fix the first ones, I can probably fix the rest).

```
1>C:\Development\huffyuv\huffyuv_a.asm(526): error A2070: invalid instruction operands
1>   MEDIAN_PREDICT_PROC(41): Macro Called From
1>    C:\Development\huffyuv\huffyuv_a.asm(526): Main Line Code
1>C:\Development\huffyuv\huffyuv_a.asm(527): error A2070: invalid instruction operands
1>   MEDIAN_PREDICT_PROC(41): Macro Called From
1>    C:\Development\huffyuv\huffyuv_a.asm(527): Main Line Code
```

I don't know very much about assembly code, so I'd be happy if someone could tell me where the problem is, and how to solve it.

Comment: Do the line numbers in the error message match the source you posted?  Line 41 is pretty harmless and shouldn't produce an error, so that makes me suspect the line numbers don't match.

Comment: I get the errors at the lines at the bottom. I guess that they are instantiations of a macro, and the error is actually somewhere in the macro, but it doesn't tell me where in the macro. Visual Studio doesn't tell me which line is line 41.

Comment: I haven't used assembly with VS 2010 so I'm not sure, but it looks to me from the error messages that it's pointing to line 41 of the macro.  So make sure the code you posted is exactly what VS sees.  Post the 10 lines of code around huffyuv_a.asm line 526 also.

Comment: I added the macro. @Carey Gregory What I posted is an exact copy-paste. Line 526 is at the bottom of the code I posted.

Comment: Also getting 6 asm errors when compiling this in VS.